# python: how to properly call the feature_importances_() for the RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I use the following code to build a random forest model, and then I try to view the importance of each feature as following:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X, Y)
rf_feature_import = rf.feature_importances_()
```

but I got the error below:

```
    rf_feature_import = rf.feature_importances_()
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: `feature_importances_` is an attribute, not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get rid of the parens it should work:

```
rf_feature_import = rf.feature_importances_
```

See here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html